# Dynamically changing partial view to display jQuery dialog MVC 4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am not sure whether this is a good way to write this code.

I have a jQuery dialog which displays a dropdown and a list of names.

When the user selects a value in the dropdown, the list has to change dynamically, including closing the dialog and opening new one, with names related to option in the dropdown.

I am using MVC 4 razor and I am displaying the dialog when a button is clicked in my View. I have a controller method which retrieves a list of names from the database based on the dropdown value.

I have a partial view Action method to display the dialog.

First I tried using ViewBag but when the dropdown value is selected, data in the dialog is not changing even if I dispose of the existing one and open a new one.

Is there any way to implement this? I have looked at some questions related to this but I have not been able to find the solution to my problem.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult selectDialog()
    {
        return PartialView("selectDialog");
    }
```

View:

```
<script>
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Select Mall">
 @Html.Partial("selectDialog")
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Select Mall">
<table><tr><td>
<p>Please Select the City</p>
<select id="scity "name="scity" onchange="getnames()">
 @foreach (var m in @ViewBag.Cities) { 
<option value="@m.Id">@m.Name</option>
    }
</select></td><td>
<p>Please Select the Name</p>
 @foreach (var n in @ViewBag.Names) { 
<input type="checkbox" name="abc">@n.Name<br>
 }
  </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.